# Convert cURL to PHP cURL - DocParser API

Tags: curl, php-curl

I have one cURL:

```
curl \
    -u <secret_api_key>: \
    -F "file=@/home/your/local/file.jpdf" \
    https://api.docparser.com/v1/document/upload/<PARSER_ID>
```

I am referring document: `https://dev.docparser.com/#import-documents`

I am not knowing how I convert `-F` to PHP cURL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to upload a file to [Docparser](https://docparser.com):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "<SECRET_API_KEY>" . ":"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.docparser.com/v1/document/upload/<PARSER_ID>');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file'=> '@' . realpath($file_name_with_full_path)));
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

You need to replace the values for `<SECRET_API_KEY>`, `<PARSER_ID>` and `$file_name_with_full_path`.